# cant upload picture from camera with Titanium

Tags: iphone, laravel-5, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I've a really strange problem with Titanium and i've search a lot of sources to solve this issue but i just can't figured it out anymore.

This is the case:
I want to upload the picture that i have just took with my Iphone to my server. The back-end is made by PHP / Laravel.

The problem:
Everytime i upload the picture titanium gives me the error: HTTP Error.

Backend:

```
$userID = Authorizer::getResourceOwnerId();
    $awsLocation = 'lonelylover.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/';

    $uploadProfilePic = new AwsUpload('source','posts/','posts/');
    $uploadProfilePic->upload();


    $posts = DB::table('Posts')->insert(
        array(
            'user_id'=>$userID,
            'Event_id'=>Request::input('event_id'),
            'description'=>Request::input('description'),
            'status'=>'public',
            'source'=>$awsLocation.$uploadProfilePic->getUploadedFile(),
        )
    );

    if($posts){
        return Response::json(array('meta'=>array('code'=>200),'data'=>"resource sucesfully created"));
    }
```

Titanium:

```
var url = "myurl.com?access_token=abcder898";
    var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'camera_photo.png');
    f.write(args.picture);


    var data_to_send = { 
        event_id: 2,
        description:"Upload from titanium",
        source:f.read()  
    };

    Ti.API.info(data_to_send);

    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function(e) {
        // this function is called when data is returned from the server and available for use
        // this.responseText holds the raw text return of the message (used for text/JSON)
        // this.responseXML holds any returned XML (including SOAP)
        // this.responseData holds any returned binary data
        Ti.API.info(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
        alert('success');
    },
    onerror: function(e) {
        // this function is called when an error occurs, including a timeout
        Ti.API.info(e.error);
        alert('error');
    },
    timeout:5000  /* in milliseconds */
});
    xhr.open("POST", url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data');
    xhr.send(data_to_send);
```

Is there anyone who can help me out with this issue because i seriously out of options.

Tnx.

Comment: And what is the Status Code?

Comment: @EduardoGomez i get a 405 status code ... i dont know why ..
this describes the 405 status code error:

Method Not Allowed The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested resource.

Comment: Okay. Got an error: [INFO]  The requested URL was not found on this server. What is the full URL you're hitting to?

Comment: The url im hitting to is on my dev environment running on Virtualbox with Homestead with Laravel installed on it.

Comment: Try another Rest Client. i.e. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/apps?hl=en Not familiar with Laravel at all. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

[Code](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/HTTPClient_and_the_Request_Lifecycle-section-29004904_HTTPClientandtheRequestLifecycle-POSTrequests) is working fine. Most likely an issue with your Backend. Talk to your web admin to set it up that allows POST requests.

Comment: thats the strange thing i've made the backend by myself with Laravel. And when i output the route list its says that the resource uri accepts only a post request:

POST     | api/v1/media                  | api.v1.media.store   projectname\Http\Controllers\PostController@store  

Strange thing is when i test the code with postmen it works fine... so thats why i get confused.